# What's the meaning of preserving the gradings?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A,B$ be two graded rings. We say a homomorphism $f:A\to B$ preserves the gradings, does it mean $f(A_n)\subset B_n \forall n\in\Bbb N$?

Comment: In theory it could mean that, but usually we take it to mean that there is some $d>0$ such that $f(A_n)\subseteq B_{dn}$. The meaning should be made clear in whatever text you're working in. For example, in Vakil they take the convention I mentioned (e.g. see 6.4.a) or the other convention (which they take in other books)